# React Child Component Not Rendering After Change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to React and am trying to create my own scrollbar. I am using a local JSON API to simulate getting data which is then listing the data as 'cards'. I built a couple of other components to organize and handle the information, it looks like this:

```
Scrollbar (Buttons to Navigate)
 |-->CardList (Handles iterating over the cards)
        |-->Cards (Template for displaying an individual card)
```

The issue I am having is that when I trigger the **Button** event *handleNext* it will successfully update **offset** & **limit** and pass these to **CardList**. However, it does not reiterate over the array and output the next 5 items. Instead it removes all the **Cards** from **CardList** and I am left with an empty screen.

**Scrollbar.js:**

```
    const { data isPending, error} = useFetch ('http://localhost:8000/data');
    const [limit, setLimit] = useState(5);
    const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);


    const handleNext = () => {
      setOffset(offset + limit);

      console.log("Offset: " +offset);
    }

    return (  
        <div className="scrollbar">
                {error && <div>{error}</div>}
                {isPending && <div>Loading...</div>}
                {data && <CardList data={data} offset={offset} limit={limit}/> }
                
                <Button onClick={handleNext}/>
         </div>
   );
}
 
export default Scrollbar;
```

**CardList.js:**

```
const CardList = ({data , offset, limit}) => {

    return ( 

        <div className="card-list" >
            {data.slice(offset,limit).map((data) => (
                <Card data={data} key={data.id}/> 
            ))}
    </div>
     );
}
 
export default CardList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when `handleNext` is triggered `offset` is going to be equal to `5` while `limit` keeps the value of `5` too, then when u do `slice(offset,limit)` is going to be replaced by `slice(5,5)` that returns an `[]`. What u want is increasing the `limit` too if u increase the `offset`, for example:

```
const handleNext = () => {
  setOffset(offset + limit);
  setLimit(limit + limit)
}
```